# prerender.io headless chrome won't start

Tags: node.js, prerender, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to start prerender with headless chrome(v62) on my Centos7 sistem but it won't start.
When running "node server.js" I get:

2017-11-23T08:50:08.329Z Starting Prerender

2017-11-23T08:50:08.331Z Starting Chrome

2017-11-23T08:50:08.343Z Prerender server accepting requests on port 3000

2017-11-23T08:50:08.392Z Chrome connection closed... restarting Chrome

2017-11-23T08:50:08.392Z Chrome died immediately after restart... stopping Prerender

Does anyone know what could be the cause?
Thank you very much

Comment: Any solution on that? In my case chrome starts succesfully (I can see that in Task Manager) but prerender server cannot connect to it

Answer (score 4):

That's because you can't run Chrome as root. Try running the command "sudo node server.js" with another user.

For this you need to add that user to Sudoers, here is a great tutorial how to do that https://www.webhostinghero.com/add-a-user-to-sudoers-in-centos-linux/

Answer (score 4):

you can also add --no-sandbox to run Chrome as root.

`vim $(which google-chrome)`

then add --no-sandbox to the last line, make it like

`exec -a "$0" "$HERE/chrome" "$@" --no-sandbox`

Answer (score 3):

solution was modifying the server.js file from the prerender module

```
var server = prerender({
  chromeFlags: ['--no-sandbox', '--headless', '--disable-gpu', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--hide-scrollbars']
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A great way to find out the underlying issue is to try running chrome on it's own.
Then if it fails it should give you an error as to why. Just find your chrome executable and pass in all the flags you're using with prerender and see what happens.

For me, chrome wasn't starting because the windows system I was running it on didn't have the required Font files that chrome needed to start up.

Although it may be windows specific, you can find more info on that here: https://github.com/prom3theu5/ServerCoreFonts